# Execute script recursively without cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have shell script which has to execute recursively.

```
Note :-
```

I don't know how much time it will take to execute the script, if I schedule crontab job, then collision will occur.please help me on this issue.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to lock the execution of the script (to forbid having several processes running it)? How often do you want the script to run? Please edit your question to improve it

Comment: I have a script. I want to execute that script recursively with different parameters. So first time script will execute with parameter value 10 and as soon as script is executed and it will restart with parameter value 20 then restart with parameter value 30 and so on.

Comment: Please define what you mean by recursive execution of a script. Show some of your script code. Your question is remaining unclear.

Comment: I have a script. I want to execute that script recursively with different parameters. So first time script will execute with parameter value 10 and as soon as script is executed and it will restart with parameter value 20 then restart with parameter value 30 and so on.

Comment: please edit your own question instead of commenting it. And please show your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you schedule it from cron, then it isn't recursive.  If you want the script to run recursively, then the answer is pretty self-evident: it should call itself.  Just add:

```
exec $0 "$@"
```

at the end of the script, and make sure that during the run you don't change the positional parameters.  (If you change them, you'll need to save their original values so you can call the script with them.)

edit--now that the question has been clarified in comments.

If you expect to receive a numeric argument and want to increment it by 10 on each run, then do:

```
exec $0 $(expr $1 + 10)
```

as the last line of the script.  But it seems somewhat silly to do this recursively, as it makes more sense to simply execute a loop in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a script in background with while loop running on it.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do 
    <Your commands Start>
    .
    .
    .
    <Your commands End>
    sleep 60 ## Comment this line if you dont want to wait for 60 seconds for                   
             ## your next execution.
done
```

Run this script in background.

```
$ ./script &
```

Comment: While the question may be unclear, could you explain how this relates to what was asked? How does this provide any type of protection against a collision between this script and the same script launched via `cron`?

Comment: Yes the question is unclear and I provided this because it seems he want to avoid the cron and this infinite loop may help him.